# $\int_{0}^{\infty}0.5 (0.5x)^{d-1} e^{-0.25x^{2}}dx=0.5\Gamma(0.5d)$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I wanted to solve this:$\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-r^2}r^{d-1}) dr$

Set $x=2r$ and I got

$\int_{0}^{\infty}0.5 (0.5x)^{d-1}  e^{-0.25x^{2}}dx$

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+0+to+inf+0.5+*+%280.5*x%29%5E%28d-1%29+*+e%5E%28-0.25*x%5E2%29+dx),
this is equal to $0.5\Gamma(0.5d)$.

But I have no idea how to prove that. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrate by substituting $u = r^2$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-r^2}r^{d-1})\,dr
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-u}u^{(d-1)/2})\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} du\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-u}u^{d/2 - 1}) du\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left( \frac{d}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
leaving us with the result from Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I tried that, but

$u=r^{2}$

$\frac{du}{dr}=2r$

$dr=\frac{du}{2r}$

Comment: nevermind, $u=r^2$ so $u=\sqrt(r)$ ($u \geq 0$ )